# Sending a POST request to WooCommerce REST API via UrlFetchApp in Google App Script return an empty response

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, httprequest, woocommerce-rest-api, urlfetch

I am trying to reproduce the following cURL post request to WooCommerce API to create a new customer:

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#create-a-customer

in Google AppScript using UrlFetchApp.

This is my code so far:

```
function newCustomer(){

  let p = {
    "ck":"myck",
    "cs":"mycs",
    "domain":"mydomain",
    "api_version":"/wp-json/wc/v3/"
  };

  let customer = {
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "username": "john.doe",
    "billing": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "shipping": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US"
    }
  }

  let endpoint = "customers";
  var url = p["domain"]+p["api_version"]+endpoint

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(p['ck']+':'+p['cs']),
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
  
  var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'headers': headers,
      'contentType' : 'application/json',
      'muteHttpExceptions': false,
      'payload':JSON.stringify(customer)
    }

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  result = JSON.parse(result);

  console.log(result);
}
```

As per the documentation, I should get a response that is not empty, but contains the information regarding the customer I uploaded using the API.

Running the code above returns a 200 status, but the response is an empty list [].

Some remarks:

- The get request to customers alone returns also an empty list. The site is new so there are still no registered customers.
- The get request to orders endpoint returns a list of dummy orders there placed while testing the e-commerce.
- I tried the request on POSTMAN with same results.

It seems to me that the get request is working fine, but in some way my post request has been interpreted as get. It seems correctly formulated to me, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think that the request for your showing script is the same request as the sample curl you provided. So, I would like to recommend checking the values in the request body and your situation on the server side, again. Even when you checked them, when your issue was not resolved, how about asking the server side? By the way, for example, when you checked the sample curl command using your values, what result did you obtain?